# JavaScript | node.js | Discord bot | Помогите разобраться с Массивом

Tags: javascript, node.js

Такая проблема, у меня есть 2 массива, к примеру эти:

```
let product = ["val_a", "val_b", "val_c", "val_d"];
let price = ["val_0", "val_1", "val_2", "val_3"];
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы значение `val_a` принадлежало значению `var_0` (`var_b -> var_1` etc), т.е. чтобы, когда я вынимал переменные `val_a и var_0`, они шли в формате: `val_a, val_0`, дабы ими можно было спокойно эксплуатировать.

пример как я себе это (эксплуатирование) представляю:

```
let product = ["val_a", "val_b", "val_c", "val_d"];
let price = ["val_0", "val_1", "val_2", "val_3"];

let item = product.find(function(verify) {
    return verify === args[0];
});

let item_price = ["val_a", "val_0"]
bot.send('Товар: ${product_price[0]}\nЦена: ${product_price[1]}')
```

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает `alert('Товар: ${product[0]}\nЦена: ${price[0]}')`?

Comment: Чем не устраивает `'Товар: ${product[0]}\nЦена: ${price[0]}'`?

Comment: не устраивает в плане того, что пользователю нужно будет написать: 
!buy productname
по проверке через 
`let verify = product.find(function(name) {
        return name === args[0];
});`
существует ли данный товар, будет присваивать значение новой переменной verify (т.е. товар, который выбрал пользователь и он есть в наличие), далее мне нужно добавить данную переменную в массив и каким-то образом присвоить определенную цену данному товару, желательно, чтобы когда я выбирал товар var_c у меня была цена var_2.
В этом и заключается моя проблема

Comment: У вас теперь пример кода вообще не рабочий. Определитесь, наконец, чего вы хотите)